# Select Elements tool not working in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I recently installed a copy of ArcGIS 10.2 on my personal laptop at home.  I'm a bit of a novice user.

I've connected the right folder on my desktop and been able to add shapefiles to my map.

The issue I have is that the select element tool does not work.  I cannot resize elements in layout view, anything I click just resizes the map.  I tried rebooting my computer. I tried restarting the application.  No dice.  No matter what I do if I am left clicking and move the mouse it zooms in (layout or design view) if I am right clicking it zooms out.

Anyone ever have this problem and have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please use descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: Argh. Newbie to the forum. Apologies.

Comment: Any chance you have a suggestion to fix my problem though?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem with 10.2 and have no clue how to resolve it. Please share if you learn of anything. I don't know if I need to reinstall or what.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than left and right-clicking all over the place, to demonstrate whether the Select Elements tool on the Tools toolbar is working I would do the following:

1. Start ArcMap with a Blank Map
2. Add in a single shapefile
3. Switch to Layout View
4. You should see the blue "handles" that indicate your data frame is selected - see graphic below.

[image]

5. Use the Select Elements tool on the Tools toolbar to click away from the data frame to see the selection handles disappear
6. Use the Select Elements tool on the Tools toolbar to click within the data frame to see the selection handles re-appear
7. Use your mouse to grab one of the handles and re-size the data frame i.e. left-click, hold, move and release.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a little embarrassed somehow after the third restart of my computer it started working properly.  Now off to relearn the basics-- and try to recall how to geocode.  It's going to be tricky, I'm not sure I have the right roads data to create an address locator.  :-/  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would check your interactive selections settings-- selection/Intereactive selection Method. Make sure you have *Create New Selection* or whatever you want activated. Otherwise just look around the selection/selection options and make sure it is set up to select your features correctly.

Otherwise you can run the check geometry tool and then repair geometry. Or to troubleshoot maybe try converting you file to another type and then reconverting it sto see if it was somehow corrupted. ie FileGDB<->Shapefile.

Comment: This question is about selecting *elements*, which are graphics, text, the dataframe, legends, scalebars, etc. - items in the mxd, not the shapefiles or other data. Two different tools/kinds of selection.